# Is ConcurrentSkipListMap.compute() safe for relative updates?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, concurrentskiplistmap

The Javadoc for [ConcurrentSkipListMap.compute(K, BiFunction)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)) states:

> Attempts to compute a mapping for the specified key and its current mapped value (or null if there is no current mapping). The function is NOT guaranteed to be applied once atomically.

I understand that the function may be invoked multiple times, but what does "once atomically" refer to?

Specifically, is it safe for the function to invoke `X = X + 1` without the map value getting incremented multiple times?

Comment: From the implementation it looks like it would be safe. I think it's just saying that the function could be called more than once.

Answer (score 2):

It is saying that:

- the function could be called more than once, and
- those calls could overlap in time; i.e. if multiple threads are calling `compute` simultaneously.

In other words, do not expect [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) behavior in the way that the function reference is called by `compute`.

---

> Specifically, is it safe for the function to invoke X = X + 1 without the map value getting incremented multiple times?

It depends on what mean by "invoke X = X + 1".  (You didn't include a clear example ....)

- If the `x = x + 1` means that you are just trying to increment the map's value, then:

  - One call to `compute` will only result in one "incrementation", because of the definition in the `compute` in `ConcurrentMap`.
  - But when you return from `compute` the value could have been incremented more than once, because another thread was doing the same thing simultaneously.
- If the `x = x + 1` refers to a *side-effect* of the method reference, then all bets are off:

  - It may have happened multiple times.
  - If your method reference is not properly synchronized, etcetera, there could be all sorts of nasty effects.  The spec implies that the `compute` call is not going to synchronize externally or call the method reference in a mutex or anything like that.  Normal concurrency / memory rules apply ...

Comment: Why would they overlap in time?

Comment: Because multiple threads could be calling `compute`.  For the same key.

Comment: Seems like a weird use of "atomically" though. By that definition, `AtomicInteger.getAndUpdate()` is not atomic either.

Comment: @shmosel - It is not a definition.  It is an anti-definition. It is a statement that is intended to dispel misconceptions / false assumptions.  But yes you are correct.   They don't strictly **need** to say "atomic".   And they could have said "not guaranteed to be called once atomically" about the call(s) to the function in `getAndUpdate`.  Instead, they simply say that the function may be called more than once ... which is probably sufficient.

Comment: @shmosel - It is a statement that is intended to dispel misconceptions / false assumptions. But yes you are correct. They don't strictly need to say "atomic". And they could have said "not guaranteed to be called once atomically" about the call(s) to the function in getAndUpdate. Instead, they simply say that the function may be called more than once ... which is probably sufficient. –

Comment: But I don't see why you suggest that is a misuse of the term "atomic".  Atomic simply means indivisible.  It is apropos here if you consider the context of multiple threads.  Apropos ... but arguably redundant.

Comment: It's not divisible. The fact that it can execute repeatedly or concurrently doesn't change that.

Comment: It is apropos in the sense that some people might expect some kind of locking to prevent the same method reference being called simultaneously by different threads.  That would be atomicity ... sort of.  (Note that this is not just a method call.  There could be hidden state associated with the method reference ... that could be updated by the call, in violation of good sense!)

Comment: So I can't tell if you answered the OP "yes" or "no."  ;-)  It seems like the answer should be "yes, once per invocation" and the atomicity stuff is referring to any internal or external state the BiFunction might rely on.

Comment: Your definition of "atomic" (indivisible / one-at-a-time) is very confusing. If you simply mean to say that the function must be free of side-effects as referenced by the second half of your answer then I suggest replacing the sentence "In other words, do not expect atomic..." with "For example..." and let users read the concrete example below.

Comment: 1) It wasn't a definition.  2) I reject your attempt to treat "users" as people who are incapable of understanding technical terms ... or looking up the definitions for themselves.

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding correctly: The overall affects of `compute` are atomic but the `BiFunction` may be called more than once while trying to perform the atomic operation? Looking at the implementations (default and otherwise) it seems to do this by trying to CAS the value until it matches the expected new value. But any time the CAS fails it needs to call the function again in order to ensure the update was applied with most recent data. Correct?

Comment: Hmmm ... sort of.  "The overall effects are atomic" is conditional on a sensible implementation of the `BiFunction`.  That matters because (as you point out) if the CAS fails you need to all the function again ... and again ... until it succeeds.   BTW, that behavior is part of the spec, not just an implementation detail; see the superclass javadocs